# How to insert new line if length of the string is bigger than x without cut the words?

Tags: c#, append, stringbuilder

I've input strings like this:

hello-my-name is Anna_B and I'm 30_years-old

> 

hello my name is

> 

hello_my_name is-Anna B

Basically, all the input strings don't follow any writting pattern and their length is variable. 
I want to add a new line in C# language if number of characteres is bigger than 15 but without cut any word.

I've tried some experiments with `StringBuilder x.AppendLine`, `string s.TakeWhile`, `string s.SkipWhile` but I'm getting troubles because I can't find any robust algorithm that works to my problem.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: do they always follow these formats? When there is a line connecting words do you care how you split?

Comment: The words of input strings are separated by an empty space, "_" and/or "-". 
The only requirement is to not cut the words. For example, the characteres of the word "Anna" should be in the same line. But "is-Anna" may be written in two lines and it's not important on which line the character "-" is placed.

Comment: stuff like this is best done with regular expressions as they are best to deal with word boundaries etc

Comment: But...How? @TheBeardedLlama

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Logic**

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> Split(string inputText, int maxLength)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i + maxLength < inputText.Length)
        {
            var lastIndexofUnderScore = inputText.LastIndexOf('_', i + maxLength);
            var lastIndexofSpace = inputText.LastIndexOf(' ', i + maxLength);
            var index = Math.Min(lastIndexofSpace, lastIndexofUnderScore);
            if (index <= 0) 
            {
                index = maxLength;
            }

            yield return inputText.Substring(i, index - i).Trim();

            i = index + 1;
        }

        yield return inputText.Substring(i).Trim();
    }
```

**Calling Method:**

```
var inputText = "hello-my-name is Anna_B and I'm 30_years-old";
var length = 15;

var expectedString = new StringBuilder();
var splittedStrings = Split(inputText, length);

foreach (var splittedString in splittedStrings)
{
    expectedString.AppendLine(splittedString);
}

Console.WriteLine(expectedString);
```

Comment: this splits words

Comment: Thank you anyway Arun Selva Kumar!

Comment: @AnnaB Updated the Code, Check Now :-)

Comment: @ArunSelvaKumar it gives me an error on this line: 
`yield return inputText.Substring(i, index - i);`

Error: Length cannot be less than zero.

Comment: I've tried many, for example: A3AAA3333-BBB, CCD1-Efgve-BoomV5, Anna B Anna B Anna, ABC_DEF_GHI.